# Как сделать лучше сравнение строк?

Tags: c, строки

**Важливо**: Дуже погано знаю російську, тому всі тексти перекладені з допомогою гугл-перекладача!

Добрый день, уважаемые господа. **Суть задачи**: *"Надо создать функцию, сравнивающую строку с образцом и возвращающую адрес вхождения подстроки в строку".*
Я думаю, что написанная мной функция ОЧЕНЬ криво сделана (хоть и работает).
Покажите как должно быть сделано и объясните почему.
(Коментарии писал с очень плохим знанием английского)

```
const char *find_a_substring(const char *string, const char *substring)
/*This function compare 'string' with 'substring' and return address of 'entry point' of substring'.*/
{
        while( *string ){
/*while string is being*/

                for(int i = 0; *(substring+i); i++){
/*while substring doesn't finish*/
                        if( !*(string+i) ){
/*if string is done - return nothing*/
                                return NULL;
                        }
                        if( *(substring+i) != *(string+i) ){
/*if char from string and char from substring doesn't equal - repeat for tail of string without one element*/
                                string++;
                                i = 0;
                                continue;
                        }
                }
/*if cicle 'for' is done but we hasn't been returned - 'string' contains our addres of substring entering*/
                return string;
        }
/*func never get there*/
        puts("NeverThere!");
        return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Можете ознакомится, как [это делают](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/string/strstr.c) / На всякий случай, прочтите [man strstr](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strstr.3.html)

Comment: Off-topic: советую "перекладачу" использовать для перевода комментов на английский.  И сравнивать со своим вариантом. Их очень сложно понимать. `if cicle 'for' is done but we hasn't been returned ` - я даже не могу понять, что на русском имелось в виду (да и украинец вряд ли догадается про украинский:-)).

Comment: обратите внимание на алгоритм [КМП](https://habr.com/ru/post/307220/). ваш код неоптимален для больших строк.

Comment: @Сергей Переклади стосуються тільки російської. Про коментарі я написав внизу. Я тільки вчуся (англійську в тому числі), тому - поки так. За пораду про перекладач на англійську - дякую, слушно!

Comment: @АлексейОбухов Дякую за посилання, зараз ознайомлюся.

Comment: Нормально он переводит на английский. С украинского в том числе. Наоборот, может и хуже.  Только фразы проще строить надо. Но дело ваше:-)

Answer (score 2):

Ну, я бы делал [так](https://ideone.com/Biuxly) — хотя решение и неоптимально, но для учебного примера (я так понимаю, речь именно о нем) сойдет. Смысл — проверяем, начиная с каждого очередного символа строки, совпадение с подстрокой.

```
const char *find_a_substring(const char *string, const char *substring)
{
    // Для пустых или отсутствующих (NULL) строк и подстрок возвращаем NULL
    if (string == NULL || substring == NULL 
                       || *substring == 0 || *string == 0) return NULL; 

    for(;*string;++string)  // Цикл по всем позициям в строке
    {
        const char *s = string, *t = substring;  // Временные переменные, чтоб не
                                                 // терять исходные значения указателей
        for(; *s && *t && *t == *s; ++s, ++t);   // Цикл сравнения строки с подстрокой. 
        // Завершается, если заканчивается строка, подстрока или если находится
        // несовпадающий символ

        // Если выход из цикла случился по завершению подстроки - значит, она найдена.
        if (*t == 0) return string;
    }
    return NULL; // Если попали сюда — подстрока не найдена
}
```